# Difference between accessing cell elements using curly braces and parentheses

Tags: matlab, cell-array

What is the difference between accessing elements in a cell array using parentheses `()` and curly braces `{}`?

For example, I tried to use  `cell{4} = []` and `cell(4) = []`. In the first case it sets the 4<sup>th</sup> element to `[]`, but in the second case it wiped out the cell element, that is, reduced the cell element count by 1.

Comment: The mathworks link [accessing cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html) explains in a very lucid manner in order to get your concepts cleared and then you are ready to play with the arrays.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB and cell array handling in for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635052/matlab-and-cell-array-handling-in-for-loop)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Think of cell array as a regular homogenic array, whose elements are all `cell`s. Parentheses (`()`) simply access the `cell` wrapper object, while accessing elements using curly bracers (`{}`) gives the actual object contained within the cell.

For example,

```
A={ [5,6], 0 , 0 ,0 };
```

Will look like this:

[image]

The syntax of making an element equal to `[]` **with parentheses** is actually a request to delete that element, so when you ask to do `foo(i) = []` you remove the *i*-th cell. It is not an assignment operation, but rather a `RemoveElement` operation, which uses similar syntax to assignment.

However, when you do `foo{i} = []` you are assigning to the i-th cell a new value (which is an empty array), thus clearing the contents of that cell.

Comment: you can see cell as a list, which stores pointers to some thing else. With () you get the pointers, with {} you get things that the pointer point to.

Comment: Another way of looking at it is that assigning to `[]` removes whatever you assign to. So `foo(i) = []` indeed removes the i-th cell, and `foo{i} = []` removes the content of the i-th cell. (Leaving nothing (`[]`) behind)

Comment: Take a look at this Octave documentation on cell arrays (MATLAB compatible ;))                                                                                       https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Indexing-Cell-Arrays.html#Indexing-Cell-Arrays]

Answer (score 3):

See the help in [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html#br04bw6-117). As you'll see, accessing with parentheses (), gives you a subset of a cell (i.e. a sub-cell), while curly braces {} gives you the content of the cell you are trying to access.

Comment: link is broken. Maybe it was pointing to https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/398071-difference-between-and#answer_317813