# Access Struct Data in Cell Matlab

Tags: matlab, struct, cell

It might be easy question for you guys, but I am new in Matlab. I have this code :

```
g = cell(2,3);
g{1,2} = struct('name','joni');
g{2,2} = cell(3,3)
g(1,2)
```

I want to display 'joni' in the answer, 
but with this code it only shows `[1x1 struct]`.

BTW I already tried this code :

```
g(1,2).name
```

and the result is error.

Comment: related question: [Difference between accessing cell elements using {} and () (curly braces vs. parentheses)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055015)

Answer (score 1):

Use curly braces instead of parentheses to refer to the *content* of a cell:

```
g{1,2}.name
```