# Accessing the contents of a 1x1 matlab cell

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I'm not sure about the terminology, but I have read data from a text file into a 1x1 cell array `P`. When examining `P`, it lists "<142x2 cell>" in the (1,1) position. From there I can double-click this and it opens up into the 142x2 cell that I actually want. The issue is, I don't get how to manipulate this data via code to convert from the 1x1 cell array to the 142x2 cell array. 
Also, I cannot find anywhere what the curly brackets denote.

Comment: What do you want? Its a 142x2 cell, what should be done with the second column? Cot off? Concatenate both columns to one?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear Daniel. Right now the data type is a 1x1 cell, {P}. When I go to look at the data of {P}, the (1,1) location simply says "<142x1 cell>", if I double click on this, it opens up to the 142x1 data I actually want. I think my terminology may be a bit off, but does this make more sense?

Comment: related question: [Difference between accessing cell elements using {} and () (curly braces vs. parentheses)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9055015/1336150)

Comment: Beginner's note. I had this issue when I had created a cell array by putting together headers and data. I had put curly brackets around it which was not necessary, deleting them let me avoid the {1} of the answers.

Answer (score 7):

> **I don't get how to manipulate this data via code to convert from the 1x1 cell array to the 142x2 cell array**.

The cell array `P` is actually a 1x1 cell array, which in turn contains *another* cell array 142x2. This type of output is very common when using `textscan`. To access the inner cell array, you can simply use curly braces (`{}`), like so:

```
Q = P{1}; // or P{:} if you're certain that P holds only one cell
```

The resulting `Q` should hold your 142x2 cell array. I usually "flatten" `P` by doing `P = P{:}`, without using an intermediate variable.

> **Also, I cannot find anywhere what the curly brackets denote.**

Have you read [MATLAB's documentation about special characters](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/specialcharacters.html)? Here's what it says:

> Curly braces are used in cell array assignment statements. For example, `A(2,1) = {[1 2 3; 4 5 6]}`, or `A{2,2} = ('str')`. See `help paren` for more information about `{ }`.

I would also urge you to read the following (very) related question: [Difference between accessing cell elements using {} and () (curly braces vs. parentheses)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9055015/1336150)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can assign the content of the first cell in `P` to `P`.

Example:

```
P = {cell(142,2)}; %Create a 142x2 cell inside a cell
P = P{1};          %Solution: Now P is a 142x2 cell
```

If you try `help cell` it will lead you to `help paren` that explains the use of curly brackets.