# Converting an cell array into string in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

I was doing some operations in Strings.I have a string 'AGCT' in X.I saved it in a cell using the following command

```
y(1,1)={x};
```

Now it is stored in a single cell.Now i want to take each letter from the string separately.I want to take A first the G and so on. Cell array conversion is necessary in this case.So how to convert the cell content back to string again??

Comment: I would call it "accessing content stored in cells" rather than "converting cells to something else". related question: [Difference between accessing cell elements using {} and () (curly braces vs. parentheses)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055015/difference-between-accessing-cell-elements-using-and-curly-braces-vs-par)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the string out of a cell with the curly braces (`{}`):

```
x='AGCT';
y(1) = {x};
y{1}
ans =    

AGCT
```

And you can string together indexing operators to get individual characters directly from the cell array.  For example:

```
y{1}(2)
ans =

G
```

---

Also keep in mind that the `char` function can convert a cell array of strings into a 2D character array by vertically concatenating the strings while padding with white space as necessary:

> `S = char(C)`, when `C` is a cell array of strings, places each element of `C` into the rows of the character array `S`.  Use `CELLSTR` to convert back.

This way you could convert your entire cell array into a 2D character array with just `char(y)`, but I think you are looking for a way to do the indexing of individual characters directly from the cell array as above.

And speaking of cell array conversion, have a look at `cellfun`, which can be used to perform the same operation on each cell.  For example, if you had a cell such as `y = {'AGCT','CTGA'};` and you wanted the second character of each cell (a character array containing `GT`), you might be tempted to do `y{:}(2)`, but this does not work (the first index must be a scalar).  A solution is:

```
>> iBase = 2;
>> basei = cellfun(@(c)c(iBase),y)
basei =
GT
```